# Best schema design to store and fetch the multiple ids in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-schema

This is second time that i can face this kind of issue to retrieve the data.

```
CREATE TABLE `pm_projects` (  
    `project_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `project_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
    `assigned_client` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    `project_detail` longtext NOT NULL,  
    `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
    `project_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`),  
    KEY `assigned_client` (`assigned_client`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

On the above table i have a field `assigned_client` that holds the multiple id's of the clients that are assigned to the project with comma separated(`3,4,...`).

And i am trying to fetch the result on this table with the **Assigned Client's Name**(that is on my `pm_users` table) with `JOIN`, I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    p.project_id, u.user_name, p.project_name, 
    p.creation_date, p.project_status
FROM pm_projects p
LEFT JOIN pm_users u ON u.user_id
IN (
    'p.assigned_clients'
)
```

that returns the `NULL` value of `u.user_name` field.

Can i have to change my schema, if yes then how?
OR i am trying with wrong Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set` for this:

```
on find_in_set(u.user_id, p.assigned_clients) > 0;
```

Note that there are no single quotes around `p.assigned_clients`.  This is another error in your query (but even if you replaced it with back quotes, the query still wouldn't work).

However, the problem is your table schema. You should have a separate association table, with one row per user and assigned client.

Trying to store this all in one field will only lead to problems, overly-complicated queries, and performance problems in the future.

Comment: **Trying to store this all in one field will only lead to problems, overly-complicated queries, and performance problems in the future.** this is what i want to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a many to many link approach.

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE pm_project_client_link(
    project_id INT,
    client_id INT
)
```

That would allow you to write the query something like

```
SELECT 
    p.project_id, 
    u.user_name, 
    p.project_name, 
    p.creation_date, 
    p.project_status
FROM    pm_projects p INNER JOIN
        pm_project_client_link pcl  ON  p.project_id = pcl.project_id INNER JOIN
        pm_users u  ON  pcl.client_id = user_id
```